# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093] with UPDATE

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to create a function to change a users password:

```
    public function ChangePassword($password)
    {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = :password WHERE id=:user_id");
        $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10]);
        $query->bindParam("password", $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        return true;
    }
```

but it shows me the "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]". When I use

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(password) VALUES (:password)");
```

instead of

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = :password WHERE id=:user_id");
```

it works, means I get an additional row with a password entry. I didn't find a documentation showing the proper use of UPDATE.

Comment: you have two parameters, but you are only binding password in your `ChangePassword` function. Try adding bindParam for :user_id as well

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a bound value for each parameter placeholder in your SQL string. No more, no fewer.

So you need something like this:

```
    $query->bindParam("user_id", $userid);
```

But I notice your function doesn't have any $userid in it. You're going to need that.

Comment: hey bill, can you please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945386/parent-id-a-foreign-keyself-referrence-and-null

Answer (score 0):

> **Do Like This:**

```
 public function ChangePassword($password,$user_id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = :password WHERE id=:user_id");
        $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10]);
        $query->bindParam("password", $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("user_id",$user_id);
        $query->execute();
        return true;
    }
```

> **NOTE:**  `bindParam` the `user_id` and also pass the `user_id` in the parameter Like this :  `ChangePassword($password,$user_id)`

Comment: this wont work either. You are not binding user_id to the placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Check the full error message, that gives quite a hint! SQLSTATE[HY093] means "Invalid parameter number"

The parameter `user_id` is missing.

```
public function ChangePassword($password, $userId)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = :password WHERE id=:user_id");
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10]);
    $query->bindParam("password", $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam("user_id", $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the current logged in user's ID is stored in a session when the user login.

Therefore this is all you need.

I believe the current logged in user's ID is stored in a session when the user login.

Therefore this is all you need.

```
 <?php
function ChangePassword($password)
{   


    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT,['cost' => 10]);

    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = :password WHERE id=:user_id")->execute(array(
        ":password" => $hash,":user_id" => $_SESSION['userid']));
    return true;
}
?>
```