# parent_id a foreign key(self reference) and null?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Going through Bill Karwin book “SQL Antipatterns”, chapter 3, Naive Trees (adjacency table, parent-child relationship) there is an example for a comment table.

```
CREATE TABLE Comments (
comment_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
parent_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
comment TEXT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Comments(comment_id)
);
```

Sample data

```
| comment_id | parent_id | comments
|------------| ----------|-------------------------------------
|1           | NULL      |What’s the cause of this bug?
|2           | 1         |I think it's a null pointer
|3           | 2         |No, I checked for that
|4           | 1         |We need to check for invalid input
|5           | 4         |Yes,that's a bug
|6           | 4         |Yes, please add a check
|7           | 6         |That fixed it
```

The table has a comment_id, parent_id and a comment column. The parent_id is a foreign key referring to the comment_id.

The comment_id auto increment starting from 1.

Question.

If parent_id is supposed to be a foreign key which refers to the comment_id then how come the row with the comment_id = 1 have parent_id null/0 when the purpose of having a foreign key is to ensure referential integrity.

Note: I created the table as it is and tried entering the data and got this error

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`category`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `comments` (`comment_id`))

Comment: If not null, what could it be? It could only be the same as the comment_Id. but since the comment_id is an auto increment column, that can't be done.

Comment: Just a head's up, when setting up FKs, both column types should be the same. In your case, one is `SERIAL`, the other is `BIGINT UNSIGNED`

Comment: @AlexTartan, thank you for the heads up, I copied the exact table as it is from the book. Yes both column type should be the same.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yes, there is no comment_id with a null/0 value in the table up top so I ask.

Comment: @BillKarwin is on stackoverflow, (https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin), how do I tag him for this question?

Comment: null and 0 are completely different things. a null is an unknown value, and that is why it can be used in a foreign key even if the referenced column have no null values. 0 is not null, and if you try to put 0 in he parent_id column you'll get the error in your question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I understand, I tried inserting the data both ways, using NULL and then 0 and had errors with both the inserts. It simply won't allow me.

Comment: perhaps it's because of the difference in data types. I myself have almost never worked with MySql, most of my experience is with SQL Server. There I can tell you things like this works ok.

Comment: The code and the data is fine and works. Also `SERIAL` is just a short form for an autoincrement column of type `BIGINT UNSIGNED`. As others mentioned, make sure to use `null`, not `0` for your root entry. And you have to enter the data in the correct order. So please add the code you are using up to getting the error (e.g. the `create table` and `insert` statements in the order you execute them, so it is reproducable what you are trying exactly).

Comment: @Solarflare, built a new db, with the table above, tried, INSERT INTO `comments`(`comment_id`, `parent_id`, `comment`) VALUES ('1','NULL','What time is ist?'), ('2','1','Well, its 5:30pm.');, after going through your comments, shows error "#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`naya`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `comments` (`comment_id`))"

Comment: @Solarflare, but if I drop the parent_id 'FK' it works.

Comment: `'NULL'` is not the same as `NULL`. Remove the `'` around `NULL` in `... VALUES ('1','NULL','...`. (You can also remove them around the `1`, as it is an integer, but MySQL will convert it correctly if you don't).

Comment: @Solarflare, INSERT INTO comments(comment_id, parent_id, comment) VALUES ('1','', 'What time is ist?'), ('2','1','Well, its 5:30pm.');.Same error

Comment: @Solarflare, Perhaps, something to do with the foreign key?. There isn't a comment_id with the value null so I guess it wouldn't allow. This works "INSERT INTO `comments`(`comment_id`, `parent_id`, `comment`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'What time is it'), ('2', '1', 'its 5:30 pm.');" Not the one with a null parent_id

Comment: `''` is not the same as `null` either! Use just `null` without anything around it: `... VALUES ('1',NULL,'What time is ist?'), ('2','1',...`. There is nothing wrong with the foreign key. The book is fine. You just have to be more precise when copying the code (or reading stackoverflow comments).

Comment: @Solarflare, it works ... thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collecting some conclusions from the comments above in this CW answer.

- The `parent_id` is `NULL` in this table for a "root" node, which is at the top of the tree and therefore has no parent.
- Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/null-values.html: Be aware that the `NULL` value is different from values such as 0 for numeric types or the empty string for string types. For more information, see Section “[Problems with `NULL` Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-null.html)”.
- Also be aware that the keyword `NULL` is not the same thing as the literal string with the word `'NULL'`.
- Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html: In MySQL `SERIAL` is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`.

Comment: Thank you Sir. First time speaking to the author of a book that I am reading. The doubts were cleared yesterday in the comment section but must add it's an honor letting you point out. Thanks again.